# Missing select and select thumbnail option in ckeditor 4

Tags: php, jquery, ckeditor, kcfinder

I'm using kcfinder integrated with ckeditor (ckeditor inline )to upload images and selecting. While selecting the image by clicking on browse server button, it was displaying images as expected. But when i right click on image it was not showing select,select thumbnail options and the image is not inserting  into the template by double clicking on the image.

Please help me in figuring out that functionality.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sudheerEva/ZDDE7/)

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {

config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = '../kcfinder/browse.php?type=images';
config.filebrowserUploadUrl = '../kcfinder/upload.php?type=images';
    config.extraPlugins = 'tokens,htmlSource,link';
    config.removePlugins = 'flash';
    config.baseFloatZIndex = 900;
    config.toolbarGroups = [
    {name: 'sourcedialog'},
    { name: 'clipboard',   groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ] },
    { name: 'editing',     groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker' ] },
    { name: 'links' },
    { name: 'insert' },
    { name: 'tools' },
    { name: 'others' },
    '/',
    { name: 'paragraph',   groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align' ] },
    { name: 'styles' },
    { name: 'colors' },
    { name: 'tokens'},
    { name: 'htmlSource'}
];


};
```

Comment: Can you please try to post your code, or in jsfiddle.net

Comment: Hi Sam, Thank you for responding. I'm giving config.js file only this file i have changed.

Comment: Code given in jsfiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/sudheerEva/ZDDE7/

Comment: I figured problem to some extent it is because of this statement this.opener.CKEditor.object.tools.callFunction(this.opener.CKEditor.funcNum, fileURL, ''); and works when i use window.opener.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(0, fileURL,'') But this will not be a generic solution

Comment: In Kcfinder path js/browser/files.js in line 166 it was checking in if condition this.opener.window. But in this variable it was undefined if i use ckeditor 4 inline editor and it was showing value if i use ckeditor 3

Answer (score 0):

Anyone who is facing the above problem

Go to path:

> kcfinder\js\browser\files.js

Add these two lines at 219

> else {   window.opener.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(0, fileURL,'');
>   window.close(); }

will resolve  the problem.

**References:**

http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_file_browser_api
http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/File_Browser_(Uploader)/Custom_File_Browser